Previous strokes deleted when i add new keyframes?
For some reason when i add new keyframes as to animate, the previous strokes get deleted? on top of that the fills remain too? Im very new and this the first time i've ever seen something like this 


you should look up auto-keying (the enabled record button at the bottom-middle of the screen) and maybe also Additive Drawing (the snowflake in the top left)

Do you add your keyframes manually or do you have Auto-Keying on? I would say that the strokes are missing because of onion-skinning, but that doesn't seem to be the case or you would see the faint outline of each brushstroke in the next keyframe.

On second thought, it could possibly have something to do with masking or your layers being in a certain order. Layers higher up in the Layer Summary hierarchy tend to hide the strokes that are in the lower layers.
